# javascript link analysis confusion

Tags: javascript

i have an html link tag  thats has a "href" attribution and I want to get domain name , it's ok to get what I want by "host" method , but what i found is very strange , take a look at this example

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask" id="test"></a>

<script>
x=document.getElementById("test");
alert(x.href.host+" , "+x.host);
</script>
```

OMG! the reusults is :
- x.href.host : undefind
- x.host : stackoverflow.com

I wounder why js considering x as a link i.e href value , but doesnt consider x.href value as a link

https://facebook.com/Programmers-286474121390882/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `x.href` is string and it did not have a property called `host`.

So try:

```
x=document.getElementById("test");
var host=x.getAttribute('href');
var pos=/:\/\//.test(host)?host.indexOf('/',7):host.indexOf('/');
host=host.substring(0,pos);
```

Thats it.
The host will be stored on variable `host`.

Comment: @Sherif Eldeeb if this solved your problem, let me know